# Create dataframe from aggregate with function

Tags: r

This is kind of a follow-up to my question at [Can I subset specific years and months directly from POSIXct datetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002066/can-i-subset-specific-years-and-months-directly-from-posixct-datetimes)

I have a dataframe

```
test <- data.frame(seq(from = as.POSIXct("1983-03-09 01:00"), to = as.POSIXct("1985-01-08 00:00"), by = "hour"))
colnames(test) <- "DateTime"
test$Value<-sample(0:100,16104,rep=TRUE)
```

and I am subsetting particular years and months using

```
# Add year column
test$Year <- as.numeric(format(test$DateTime, "%Y"))

# Add month column
test$Month <- as.numeric(format(test$DateTime, "%m"))

# Subset specific year (1984 in this case)
sub1 = subset(test, Year!="1983" & Year!="1985")

# Subset specific months (April and May in this case)
sub2 = subset(test, Month=="4" | Month=="5")
```

From these subsets `sub1` and `sub2`, I want to use the hourly data to calculate daily minimum, mean, and maximum from column `Value`.

I found a solution at [Aggregating hourly data into daily aggregates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200437/aggregating-hourly-data-into-daily-aggregates)

```
stat <- function(x) c(min = min(x), max = max(x), mean = mean(x))
sub1$Date <- as.Date(sub1$DateTime)
sub2$Date <- as.Date(sub2$DateTime)
aggregate(Value ~ Date, sub1, stat)
aggregate(Value ~ Date, sub2, stat)
```

This appears to give the minimum, mean, and maximum in columns (although I can't verify as I can't read the top in the R output window).  I need to make these `aggregate` results into a dataframe containing `Date`, `min`, `mean`, and `max`.  Does anyone know how I might do that?  I've tried

```
sub1.sum <- aggregate(Value ~ Date, sub1, stat)
```

and

```
sub1.sum <- as.data.frame(aggregate(Value ~ Date, sub1, stat))
```

but that appears to just return a single value (i'm not sure if this is the min, mean, or max).

Comment: Ok when I run your code `aggregate(Value ~ Date, sub1, stat)` returns  `Date Value.min Value.max Value.mean
1   1984-01-01   1.00000  76.00000   41.93750
.   ..........   .......  ........   ........`       Is that not what you wanted.

Comment: Hello CCurtis, yes that is what I wanted, but I would like to store those results in a dataframe with columns for date, min, mean, and max.  Do you know how I might do that?  My attempts thus far (above) have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cbind(sub1.sum[,-2, drop=FALSE], as.data.frame(sub1.sum$Value))` gives you what you want, I guess. The problem before was the the value column consisting of 3 dimensions (min, mean, max)...

Comment: Nice. Ok trying to understand how you answer works. What does indexing with -2 do? I've never had a problem like this where R will show you data but not allowing you to put it in a table.

Comment: -2 means all columns but the second. You could also say `sub1.sum[,1, drop=FALSE]` to only keep the first column (Dates). `drop=FALSE` prevents from converting a single column dataframe into a vector. So what the code does in total is: pasting together (cbind is for column bind) the Dates column with the three columns in Value.

Comment: Ok and calling `sub1.sum$Value` is just returning min max mean I'm assuming. Mainly hadn't seen negative values used to index before. Is a good trick to know. Also interesting to know that `aggregate` was adding three values into a single column but only returning 1 and not reporting any error.